# I don't understand how the diameters of $ \bar A$ and $A$ are equal

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm given the assignment to prove that $\operatorname{diam}\bar A = \operatorname{diam}A$, where $\operatorname{diam}A=\sup\{\rho(a,b): a,b \in A\}.$

How can they be equal if $\bar A= \partial A \cup A$:

Say $x\in \partial A$, then does it not follow that $x > a, \; x> b$, thus $ x \notin A$ ?

Comment: What is$\rho(a,b)$ ?  Are you sure that the set A is defined as it is ?

Comment: I have guessed that you're working on a metric space and $\rho$ is the given metric. I also fixed your definition, adding “diam” and “sup”.

Comment: Because it is the supremum. $\mbox{diam } A=\sup \{d(a,b):a,b\in A\}$.

Comment: @Mohammad it is distance between two points in metric space. I suppose it is defined as d(a,b) commonly.

Comment: @egreg: not inf. Then it would be zero.

Comment: @egreg, it is given as sup in assignment.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, fixed

Comment: Don't worry :).

Comment: @dog isn't supremum in this case greatest distance between points a and b in A?

Comment: If $a,b,x$ are points in a metric space, then what could it mean to say $x>a$ or $x>b \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the intervals $(0,2)$ and $[0,2]$. One is open -- not containing either $0$ or $2$. The other is closed -- containing both $0$ and $2$.

The length of both these intervals is $2-0 = 2.$

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\subseteq\bar{A}$, it is obvious that $\operatorname{diam}A\le\operatorname{diam}\bar{A}$.

If $\operatorname{diam}A=\infty$, there is nothing to prove, so we can assume $\operatorname{diam}A$ is finite.

Suppose $\operatorname{diam}\bar{A}>\operatorname{diam}A$. Then there are $x,y\in\bar A$ such that $\rho(x,y)>\operatorname{diam}A$.

Let $\varepsilon=(\rho(x,y)-\operatorname{diam}A)/2$. Then, since $x,y\in\bar{A}$, there are $a,b\in A$ such that $\rho(a,x)<\varepsilon$ and $\rho(b,y)<\varepsilon$. By applying the triangle inequality we have
$$
\rho(x,y)
\le\rho(x,a)+\rho(a,y)
\le\rho(x,a)+\rho(a,b)+\rho(b,y)<
\varepsilon+\operatorname{diam}A+\varepsilon<\rho(x,y)
$$

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily have any ordering among the points of the metric space (consider e.g. $\Bbb R^n$), so your statements $x>a$ and $x>b$ are meaningless.

To prove the claim, take any $a, b\in\bar A$ and consider *sequences* $a_n, b_n\in A$ with $a_n\to a, \ b_n\to b$, and note that $\rho(a_n, b_n) \to\rho(a, b) $.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show  $$\operatorname{diam}\bar A = \operatorname{diam}A$$

Obviously $$\operatorname{diam}A \le\operatorname{diam}\bar A  $$

On the other hand if $$\operatorname{diam}A <\operatorname{diam}\bar A  $$ we have two points in the $\bar A$ whose distance is greater than $\operatorname{diam}A$

At least one of these points must be in  $\partial A $

That implies that the point in the boundary is included in an open ball which does not intersect A.

That contradicts the definition of  $\partial A $

Comment: >That implies that the point in the boundary is included in an open ball which does not intersect A.

How does it imply that open ball of the point in $\partial A$ does not intersect $A$ ?

Comment: The distance between two points is greater than the diameter so one of these points, say $b$  is on the boundary. The distance minus the diameter is 
 $ r>0$. The open ball  B(b;r/2)  does not intersect A, due to the  triangle inequlity.